# Python dropping UDP packet that WireShark sees

Tags: python, udp, embedded, bare-metal

I'm attempting to send a UDP packet from a baremetal embedded device to a script running python.
I see the packet in WireShark and confirmed that everything is correct.
However, the Python script does not see the packet.

I've tested the python code by sending a UDP packet from another python script.  The receiving python script does receive it at that point.

I see the packet in the FireWall.  It says the packet was allowed and sent to python.  I've created a rule in the FireWall to allow traffic from this device.  I've also tried disabling the FireWall.

Below is my python script listening for the UDP packet

```
import socket

UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind(('', UDP_PORT))

while True:
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
  print "received message:", data
  print "received from:", addr
```

Why would Python drop the packet?

Netstat shows it received the UDP packet without any errors:

Netstat before receiving the packet

> netstat -s -n -p UDP
>
> UDP Statistics for IPv4
>
> Datagrams Received    = 5982014
>
> No Ports              = 79096
>
> **Receive Errors        = 829**
>
> Datagrams Sent        = 1641811

Netstat after receiving the packet

> netstat -s -n -p UDP
>
> UDP Statistics for IPv4
>
> Datagrams Received    = 5982130
>
> No Ports              = 79100
>
> **Receive Errors        = 829**
>
> Datagrams Sent        = 1641932

Comment: *"The fact WireShark see's the packet confirms that the OS knows the port is open and something is listening to it."* - No, it doesn't. Capturing packets work no matter if the port is open or not or if a local firewall is blocking the packet. It just shows what packets are received by the network card and not what is actually forwarded to the application. But if that the script is able to receive data from some other system it is more likely that the UDP packet is malformed and discarded by the kernel. It  will still be visible in wireshark though.

Comment: You're right.  I thought I tested this by closing the python script and sending it.  I didn't see the packet in wireshark at this point.  But I just tested it again and that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich. The packet doesn't seemed to be malformed in WireShark.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I see the traffic in the firewall.  Wouldn't that suggest that the kernel is not dropping it?

Comment: *"I see the traffic in the firewall"* - I don't know what you mean with this. But - if your script is able to receive the intended packets from another machine and only fails to  receive it from your embedded device then it is very likely that the problem is not caused by your program (the recipient) but by the sender (the embedded system). This means you only provide information about the part of your setup which is likely not the problem but not about the other part which is very likely the problem.

Comment: I think you're right. It seems to work when I set the UDP checksum to 0.

Comment: Have you tested/compared the effect of sending a UDP packet from a different source, e.g. a python script on the (or another) PC?

Comment: Did you able to figure out the problem? I am facing similar problem with Dot Net Udp socket.

Comment: Same here. Trying to implement it with `asyncio.DatagramProtocol`, I am able to send broadcast messages, I see the replies in Wireshark but `datagram_received` never gets executed.